# How to extract Vein Pattern from these images in Opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, pattern-recognition

I want to extract the vein patterns from the attached images. I am trying to code a Vein pattern recognition system. I tried the Canny Edge Detector for getting the edges of the veins but somehow they are not very clear. Any improvisations or other techniques would be greatly appreciated. For information, I am trying to write a C++ Code in OpenCV on Ubuntu.

ROI
[image: ROI]
Source
[image: Source]
Canny
[image: Canny]

Comment: Is that image blurred? If yes, do you have access to the original image? Maybe even color image?

Comment: The image is not blurred. I am using an IR webcam to capture the vein patterns.

Comment: are you able to change exposure times and/or lighting conditions?
Is it FIR or NIR?

Comment: I might be able to change the exposure time but the lighting conditions would be the same. It's a Night vision camera I suppose it's NIR.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that simple thresholding or edge detection methods will work reliably - I expect that you will have to tune them individually to each image. With respect to thresholding you will definitely have to look at adaptive methods.

You could try to apply a band-pass filter tuned for the frequency band of the veins to get a more normalised image, i.e. an image where the gray level of "vein" and "background" is more similar over the image. This could make subsequent thresholding steps more reliable.

I think an industry-strength solution would have to use something more sophisticated than simple image processing tools.

Comment: I shall try the same and revert. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try some thresholding methods.  There are some that are adaptive and region based.  You could also try using some other kernels other than the standard Canny kernels.  How you proceed is heavily dependent on how you want to use the output and what the other images look like in comparison.

Comment: I want to create a database of vein patterns and perform matching of a captured vein pattern with the database.